# How do I create scrolling views?

Tags: views

I want to scroll my views, but I don't find a module that allows this.

Is there a module for scrolling views? How can I scroll views, if there isn't a module with that purpose?

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for scrolling similar to Twitter, try the [Views Infinite Scroll](http://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module.

If you're looking for something more like [this site](http://downtothewire.co.nz/the-beginning-1989/), try the [Geared Scrolling](http://drupal.org/project/geared_scrolling) module (DISCLAIMER: which I maintain).

Comment: For more info on how to set up [Views infinite scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) please follow this link: [Setup Views Infinite Scroll in Drupal](http://www.drupaldock.com/content/setup-views-infinite-scroll-drupal).

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said [Views Infinite Scroll](http://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) can be used for achieving scroll based Pagination.
For more info on how to set it up please follow this link: http://www.drupaldock.com/content/setup-views-infinite-scroll-drupal

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Note that an answer with only a link is not regarded as a good answer. Links to external resources are encouraged, but always quote the most relevant part of an external link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Please see [How to write a good answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).